# Quillen adjunction betwen simplicial presheaves and cochain complexes

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-presheaves

Let $sPsh(\mathcal{C})$ the category of simplicial presheaves over a small category $\mathcal{C}$. Let $Ch^{*}_{\geq 0}$ be the category of positively graded cochain complexes of modules over a field of characteristic zero. Suppose that we have a Quillen adjunction
$$
L\: : \:sPsh(\mathcal{C})\leftrightarrows Ch^{*}_{\geq 0},\: R$$
and let $f,g\: : \: X\to Y$ be two (left) homotopic maps in $sPsh(\mathcal{C})$. My Question:

1)When are $L(f), L(g)$ again left homotopic maps? I know that this is true when $X$ is cofibrant (for arbitrary model categories), do you know some weaker conditions for this case?

2)Thanks to Geoffroy Horel: I know that there is a Dold-Kan equivalence between the category of cochain modules (positively graded) and cosimplicial modules. this should induce a simplicial model category structure on $Ch^{*}_{\geq 0}$ (is it true?), thus if $L$ is simplicial, then it preserves left homotopies.

Additional question: Now replace $Ch^{*}_{\geq 0}$ with the category of associative differential unitary graded algebras:

-is the category of differential graded associative unitary algebras a simplicial model category? What is the "tensor" and "cotensor functor"?

Thanks!!

Comment: Both model categories are in fact simplicial model categories. If $L$ is a simplicial functor then it preserves all left homotopies.

Comment: This observation is helpfull, do you know some references about the simplicial model structure on $Ch^{*}_{\geq 0}$? It is possible obtain this structure from the category of cosimplicial modules via Dold-Kan?

Comment: I read your question a bit too fast. I thought you meant chain complexes. I'm not sure cochain complexes form a simplicial model category. This is true for chain complexes and as you said, this can be done via Dold-Kan.

Comment: @GeoffroyHorel Chain complexes is not simplicial either since Dold-Kan does not strictly preserve tensor products.

Comment: @Cepu since $L$ and $R$ are arbitrary, I can't imagine how the specification of the model categories might help. Maybe if you specify what functors you have in mind people can help.

Comment: @FernandoMuro Yeah, you're right. I guess I meant that $X\mapsto X\otimes C_*(\Delta^1)$ is a cylinder functor in chain complexes.